# New Math.random's / Restarting swf / Constant random numbers

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a dice game that throws 2 dice. One is yours and one is the "computer's".
If the "computer's" dice is higher or equal to yours, you lose.

I have 12 seperate symbols for each dice roll (1-6 of your dice, 1-6 of the "computer's" dice).
I used this code to get a random dice roll every time I re-open the swf:

```
var diceplayer:int = 1;
diceplayer = Math.random()*6 + 1; //(the +1 so you don't get 0)
```

How do I go about making a re-try button that rerolls the 2 dice, with a different Math.random? Usually when I declare a Math.random it stays the same for the entire time until I restart the swf.

I hope I supplies enough information.

Thank you for any support you can give me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using Array to get random Number

> var testArr:Array = new Array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
>   var gotRandonNumber:int = testArr[int(Math.random() * testArr.length)];

May these will helpfull

Comment: Can you also possibly explain how I remove items effectively from my scene? Because if I try to use remove(); they(bug) say it doesn't exsist(it's null already because it doesn't exsist yet). And I added the symbols for each dice after i pressed the button. So my question: "How do i check if a symbol is added through addChild, and how do i then remove it ?" Thank you for your help!

Comment: removeChild is the method to remove a symbol.
see More about [addChild and removeChild](http://coursesweb.net/actionscript/addchild-removechild)

Comment: Whenever I do that I get this error: "Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference." I think it's because it's not on stage yet. How do I properly do it? After I changed it around it didn't gave me that error anymore, but it still won't remove the symbols.

My code now:

"if(diceone)
 {
  removeChild(diceone);
  trace(diceone);
 }
"
It doesn't remove it I think

Comment: See example..
[remove from stage](http://asgamer.com/2009/as3-flash-games-for-beginners-how-to-make-enemies-with-basic-ai)

Comment: I tried the stage.contains(diceone)) stage.removeChild(diceone);
But it gave me this error:
"Parameter child must be non-null."

Answer (score 1):

A new call to Math.random() does return a new random number. I just tried that here: http://wonderfl.net/c/rrv3.

code:

```
package {
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    public class FlashTest extends Sprite {
        public function FlashTest() {

            mText = new TextField();
            addChild(mText);

            mText.text = Math.random().toString();
            mText.text = mText.text + '\n' + Math.random().toString();
        }

        private var mText:TextField;
    }
}
```

I think you'd need to post more code for someone to identify and solve the issue you might be facing.

Comment: What does the "toString" exactly do? Thank you for the help!

Comment: toString() is just to conver Number (as returned from Math.random()) to String (the type of mText.text).